# How can I update previous logs from winston in the console?

Tags: javascript, typescript, winston

I need to use multiple logger instances at the same time, so the logs of all loggers need to be updated on each line of each logger

How can I do this?

I tried to use one instance logger, but the logs is unreadable and hard to understand

---

**That's a example of what I wanted**:
Example code:

```ts
Logger.getLogger("A").info("test1: A");
Logger.getLogger("B").info("Message with label: B");
Logger.getLogger("A").info("test2: A");
```

Output should be:

```ts
2022-12-11T14:49:39.829Z info [A]     test2: A // prev log was 'test1: A'
2022-12-11T14:49:39.828Z info [B]     Message with label: B
```

Comment: What is logger. What logger is used. What is actual output.

Comment: @Dimava ,  as you can see there is a tag [winston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winston),so i use winston logger

Comment: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1017

Comment: @morganney, its not what i need,i updated example